# Deploy symfony project: Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation now in progress while accessing http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git/info/refs

Tags: symfony, capifony

I use capifony, and I deploy my symfony project into my server.

I have seen that I have a problem:

```
*** [err :: server.com] error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation now in progress while accessing http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git/info/refs
*** [err :: server.com] 
*** [err :: server.com] fatal: HTTP request failed
*** [err :: server.com] sh: line 0: cd: /home/app/src/releases/20120213081637/vendor/symfony: No such file or directory
*** [err :: server.com] error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation now in progress while accessing http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git/info/refs
*** [err :: server.com] 
*** [err :: server.com] fatal: HTTP request failed
*** [err :: server.com] sh: line 0: cd: /home/app/src/releases/20120213081637/vendor/twig: No such file or directory
*** [err :: server.com] error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation now in progress while accessing http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git/info/refs
*** [err :: server.com] 
*** [err :: server.com] fatal: HTTP request failed
*** [err :: server.com] sh: line 0: cd: /home/app/src/releases/20120213081637/vendor/monolog: No such file or directory
*** [err :: server.com] error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation now in progress while accessing http://github.com/doctrine/common.git/info/refs
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work

Please

any help will be cool

Thanks

Sam

Comment: the similar question was here yesterday. change http to https (git)?

Comment: Hi thanks, I have change the [symfony]
    git= http ://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.10 to [symfony]
    git=https ://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.10 but error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/symfony/symfony.git/info/refs doing php ./bin/vendors install --reinstall

Comment: And if you change it to git://?

Comment: I have a problem, it seems that I oesn't take into account my deps file. Is it right that I have only to change the deps file before deploying using capifony?

Comment: I think yes, capifony is just a bunch of commands to make deployment easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cool. The problem come from the url. You have to change http:// to git://

Thanks meze